# Number of unit squares that meet a given diagonal line segment in more than one point

Tags: combinatorics

Let $l$, $b$ be positive integers. Divide the $l \times b$ rectangle into $lb$ unit squares in the usual manner. Consider one of the two diagonals of this rectangle. How many of these unit squares contains a segment of positive length of this diagonal?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?  Any common factor of $l$ and $b$ might affect the result.

Answer (score 7):

The diagonal line will cross $b$ squares (in the $b$ direction) and $l$ squares (in the ($l$ direction), These ($b$ and $l$ directions) will count separately toward the total number of squares cut except for $\gcd(l,b)$ occasions when the diagonal makes the transition from one row to the next in both directions through a grid point. This counts the start/end corners as "half a grid point" each, by analogy with the $2b \times 2l$ rectangle.

Thus the total number of squares with a portion of the diagonal will be $l+b-\gcd(l,b)$.

[image]

For the illustration, $l=8, b=12$ and the diagonal goes through $\gcd(12,8)=4$ grid points for a total of $12+8-4=16$ squares cut.

Comment: The formula is correct, but I find the explaing text very confusing. Specialising to the example "The diagonal line will cross $8$ squares and $12$ squares, but for $4$ occasions will accomplish the transition through a corner." The sentence does not even really make sense (a transition is not a square) but I have a hard time seeing those $8$ and $12$ squares. And in the diagram the diagonal clearly goes through $5$ lattice points (corners), or $3$ if one does not count the end points (actual corners); the only way one can get $4$ is counting the end points half, or making an asymmetric choice

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - thanks for the comment. Added some more explanation, let me know if it has helped at all.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the requested number $f(l,b)$, and putting $d=\gcd(l,b)$, one has $f(l,b)=d f(\frac ld,\frac bd)$. This is because cutting the diagonal into $d$ pieces of equal length, the subdivision points are lattice points (in fact they are precisely the lattice points on the diagonal), and all $d$ pieces are similar.

This reduces the problem to the case where $l,b$ are relatively prime. Now there are no intermediate lattice points, so every time the diagonal passes from a previous square into a new square, it either does so horizontally or vertically, but not both. Now use the fact that you pass into a new square horizontally $l-1$ times in all, and vertically $b-1$ times in all. That makes for $1+(l-1)+(b-1)=l+b-1$ squares in all, the initial $1$ counting the square one is in before passing to a new square for the first time.

For the general case one then finds 
$$f(l,b)=d f(\frac ld,\frac bd)=d(\frac ld+\frac bd-1)=l+b-d, \qquad\text{where $d=\gcd(l,b)$.}
$$

Comment: your answer is not working, say take $l=3$ and $b = 2$; the correct answer is 4, but yours one is 3, i guess. Something is wrong in your argument.

Comment: @RakeshBalhara: No, what I count is the number of _passages into a new square_. Since you already are in a square right from the start, you should add $1$, giving $l+b-1$ for the relatively prime case.

Comment: @RakeshBalhara : For a (3 x 2) and considering the formula by Marc Van Leeuwen we will have No. of squares which contain the diagonal = 3+2 - gcd(3,2) = 3+2 -1 = 5-1 = 4

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am confused with the idea $1+(l-1)+(b-1)$ for a 2*4 rectangle. Since then We will have $ 1+ (2-1)+(4-1) = 1+1+3 = 5$ but if we consider the general case we will have $ 2+4- gcd(2,4) = 2+4-2 = 4$ Whence, 4 is the correct answer. Please correct my fault.

Comment: That formula $1+(l-1)+(b-1)$ is in the paragraph treating the case where $l,b$ are relatively prime; since $2$ and $4$ are not relatively prime, the paragraph (and the formula) does not apply there. For the non relatively prime case there are the first and last paragraph; the final and general formula is $l+b-\gcd(l,b)$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: To be frank I want to know the approach which you used to formulate this $f(l,b)=d f(\frac ld,\frac bd)$. It might be trivial but I am not able to connect with the idea behind it.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Let us move the discussion here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39161/math-station

Answer (score 0):

Having read multiple answers, I could not help myself help report that there is a very elementary approach to an answer.

The first step is to compute the slope. Which is $s = b/l$,  if the ratio is irreducible to simple fractions, then you must walk $l$ steps forward to get an integer $b$. Then, $gcd(b,l) = 1$, but for now, this is only mathematical jargon which, to me side steps from the actual elementary argument.

Coming back to the above, the act of walking $l$ steps to get to $b$ means you have not encountered any vertices of any square by walking $1, 2,3,4,...,l-1$ steps. You will encounter a vertex at the very end.